# GeoServer REST API (geoserver-restconfig) create coverage store and mosaic error

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I am working on Ubuntu 18 and using Kartoza GeoServer docker v:2.15. I try to push Landsat band 4 (for sample I have two images epsg_4326) with Python library geoserver-restconfig to GeoServer with coverage store with below code

```
cat.create_coveragestore( 'name112', workspace=None, path='file:ndvi_4326/1.tif', type='GeoTIFF',create_layer=False, layer_name=None, source_name=None, upload_data=False,contet_type="image/tiff",overwrite=False)
```

when create layer is 'False' I can create store but if it is 'true' I get an error

> 'FailedRequestError: Failed to create coverage/layer 1 for : name12, 400'

I got same error when I was trying with create_imagemosaic function.

```
cat.create_imagemosaic('band4','file:ndvi_4326',configure='all',workspace='ndvi')

~/Desktop/django_tutorial/djangoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geoserver/catalog.py in create_imagemosaic(self, name, data, configure, workspace, overwrite, charset)
    532             resp = self.http_request(url, method='put', data=upload_data, headers=headers)
    533             if resp.status_code != 201:
--> 534                 raise FailedRequestError('Failed to create ImageMosaic {} : {}, {}'.format(name, resp.status_code, resp.text))
    535             self._cache.clear()
    536         finally:    
   FailedRequestError: Failed to create ImageMosaic band22 : 400,
```

I think, when trying to create layer I get an error and I checked to code I couldn't find anything. Any suggestions for this problem?

Edit-1
I tried image mosaic code in Windows machine and it worked. What is the source of error? GeoServer setting? or Docker settings?

Also I opened github issue 
https://github.com/GeoNode/geoserver-restconfig/issues/3

Comment: Please place error messages in the Question body as text (images, even without a black background, are not legible on all devices, and they are not text searchable by others, which hides the answer from others).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The path should be like  'file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/ndvi2'

cat.create_imagemosaic('ndvi','file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/ndvi2',configure='all',workspace='ndvi')